# C++20 concepts for container and allocator

Tags: c++, c++20, constrained-templates

I implemented concepts for container and allocator types. I referenced type requirements from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) for container and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) for allocator.

For the sake of simplicity, there are a lot of type aliases declared in the template because [concept itself does not allow declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332980/c-concepts-lite-and-type-alias-declaration).

I'm also concerned that many parts of the code are duplicate or irrelevant as of C++20.

For example, I excluded `A::template rebind<U>::other` from the requirements since it is removed in C++20. And, the allocator itself no longer requires methods other than `allocate` and `deallocate`.

Here is the entire code. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>

namespace phd {

template<typename T>
concept copy_assignable = std::is_copy_assignable_v<T>;

template<typename T>
concept move_assignable = std::is_move_assignable_v<T>;

template<typename T>
concept nullable_pointer =
    std::equality_comparable<T> &&
    std::default_initializable<T> &&
    std::copy_constructible<T> &&
    copy_assignable<T> &&
    std::destructible<T> &&
    requires (T p, T q) {
        { T(nullptr) }   -> std::same_as<T>;
        { p = nullptr }  -> std::same_as<T&>;
        { p != q }       -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
        { p == nullptr } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
        { nullptr == p } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
        { p != nullptr } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
        { nullptr != p } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
    };

template<
    typename Alloc,
    typename T                  = Alloc::value_type,
    typename pointer            = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer,
    typename const_pointer      = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::const_pointer,
    typename void_pointer       = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::void_pointer,
    typename const_void_pointer =
        std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::const_void_pointer,
    typename size_type          = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::size_type,
    typename difference_type    = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::difference_type
>
concept allocator =
    nullable_pointer<pointer> &&
    std::random_access_iterator<pointer> &&
    std::contiguous_iterator<pointer> &&
    nullable_pointer<const_pointer> &&
    std::random_access_iterator<const_pointer> &&
    std::contiguous_iterator<const_pointer> &&
    std::convertible_to<pointer, const_pointer> &&
    nullable_pointer<void_pointer> &&
    std::convertible_to<pointer, void_pointer> &&
    nullable_pointer<const_void_pointer> &&
    std::convertible_to<pointer, const_void_pointer> &&
    std::convertible_to<const_pointer, const_void_pointer> &&
    std::convertible_to<void_pointer, const_void_pointer> &&
    std::unsigned_integral<size_type> &&
    std::signed_integral<difference_type> &&
    std::copy_constructible<Alloc> &&
    std::move_constructible<Alloc> &&
    copy_assignable<Alloc> &&
    move_assignable<Alloc> &&
    std::equality_comparable<Alloc> &&
    requires(Alloc a) {
        typename T;

        // *p
        {*std::declval<pointer>()} -> std::same_as<T&>;

        // *cp
        {*std::declval<const_pointer>()} -> std::same_as<const T&>;

        // static_cast<Alloc::pointer>(vp)
        requires
            std::same_as<
                decltype(static_cast<T*>(std::declval<void_pointer>())),
                pointer
            >;

        // static_cast<Alloc::const_pointer>(cvp)
        requires
            std::same_as<
                decltype(static_cast<const_pointer>(
                    std::declval<const_void_pointer>())),
                const_pointer
            >;

        // std::pointer_traits<Alloc::pointer>::pointer_to(r)
        {std::pointer_traits<pointer>::pointer_to(*std::declval<pointer>())}
            -> std::same_as<pointer>;

        {a.allocate(std::declval<size_type>())} -> std::same_as<pointer>;

        {a.deallocate(std::declval<pointer>(), std::declval<size_type>())}
            -> std::same_as<void>;
    };

template<typename T, typename Alloc>
concept erasable = requires(Alloc m, T* p) {
    {std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::destroy(m, p)} -> std::same_as<void>;
};

template<typename T, typename Alloc>
concept move_insertable = requires(Alloc m, T* p, T&& rv) {
    {std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct(m, p, rv)} -> std::same_as<void>;
};

template<typename T, typename Alloc>
concept copy_insertable =
    move_insertable<T, Alloc> &&
    requires(Alloc m, T* p, const T& v) {
        {std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct(m, p, v)}
            -> std::same_as<void>;
    };

template<typename Iter, typename Container>
concept container_iterator =
    std::same_as<Iter, typename Container::iterator> ||
    std::same_as<Iter, typename Container::const_iterator>;

template<
    typename Container,
    typename C               = Container,
    typename T               = C::value_type,
    typename Alloc           = C::allocator_type,
    typename value_type      = T,
    typename reference       = C::reference,
    typename const_reference = C::const_reference,
    typename iterator        = C::iterator,
    typename const_iterator  = C::const_iterator,
    typename difference_type = C::difference_type,
    typename size_type       = C::size_type
>
concept container =
    erasable<T, Alloc> &&
    requires() {
        typename reference;
        typename const_reference;
    } &&
    std::forward_iterator<iterator> &&
    std::convertible_to<iterator, const_iterator> &&
    std::forward_iterator<const_iterator> &&
    std::signed_integral<difference_type> &&
    std::same_as<difference_type,
        typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::difference_type> &&
    std::same_as<difference_type,
        typename std::iterator_traits<const_iterator>::difference_type> &&
    std::unsigned_integral<size_type> &&
    std::default_initializable<C> &&
    std::copy_constructible<C> &&
    std::equality_comparable<C> &&
    std::swappable<C> &&
    copy_insertable<T, Alloc> &&
    std::equality_comparable<T> &&
    std::destructible<T> &&
    requires (C a) {
        { a.~C() }       -> std::same_as<void>;
        { a.begin() }    -> container_iterator<C>;
        { a.end() }      -> container_iterator<C>;
        { a.cbegin() }   -> std::same_as<const_iterator>;
        { a.cend() }     -> std::same_as<const_iterator>;
        { a.size() }     -> std::same_as<size_type>;
        { a.max_size() } -> std::same_as<size_type>;
        { a.empty() }    -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
    };

}
```

Comment: Add `requires` before `requires (C a)`. Explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200988/why-do-we-require-requires-requires

Comment: @isnullxbh `requires requires` only applies to function and class. When declaring `concept`, a single `requires` clause serves as a boolean expression.

Comment: Check the following [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2h1nHRCCya5GKap4). GCC doesn't compile it (without second requires), Clang generates a warning.

Comment: @isnullxbh I think you misunderstood what I said. A single `requires` clause is used to apply constraints on subsequent stuff (function, class). The first `requires` from `requires requires` also does the same thing. But the latter one is a boolean constant expression. Unless you intentionally nest `requires` inside `requires` block just like the example you gave, a single `requires` is valid.

Comment: As stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), `requires` does two things: specifying constraints and boolean expression. The one used in my code represents the latter. Therefore, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I was inattentive and thought that this `requires` is nested in other `requires`. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're perhaps overdoing the constraints (and perhaps trying to catch out Machiavelli, rather than to help Murphy).  I'd write the nullable pointer type much more simply:

```
template<typename T>
concept nullable_pointer =
    std::regular<T> && std::assignable_from<T, nullptr_t>;
```

The `allocator` and `container` concepts have a lot of optional template parameters that aren't really useful to specify (and can be actively harmful).  I recommend removing those and replacing their use with the current default values.  This will give simpler error messages.

Quite a lot of `container` is included in `std::ranges::common_range` concept.